# Compare two collections and add/remove from one to make them match

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two database tables that represent lists of items that belong to parent entities.

I need to periodically update table B to match table A

using linq, I get a collection of the IDs in table A.

I now need to add and remove rows from table B to make it match up with A.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this using linq and EF 4.1?

I can loop through the A collection and, within this loop, loop through B checking for a record that matches the current item in the outer loop, adding the new item if no match is found... however it seems like i would then need to loop through B a second time to remove any items that are not in A. This seems inefficient. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var toRemove = tableB.Except(tableA);
var toAdd = tableA.Except(tableB);
```

where `tableA` and `tableB` are lists of IDs.

And then it's easiest to `foreach()` trough both result lists and perform the necessary actions.

Comment: So to make sure i have this right. I would loop through B and remove all items in the toRemove list and add everything from the toAdd list?

Comment: Yep, that would do it. You're lucky not to have changed records.

Comment: thanks! nope just need to add and set active/inactive flags really.